# Storing records to temporary table inside dynamic query when using Pivot.

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table, temp-tables

I am new to sql programming.

I want to store the records returned as result set from the pivot query.

Pivot's columns are selected dynamically.

My query is:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

set @cols=STUFF((select distinct ',[' + LTRIM(rtrim(year(Dt)))+']' from temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

EXEC('select * from 
(select YEAR(Dt)[year],Software,Ver from temp)T
Pivot(count([year]) for [year] in ('+@cols+'))PVT')
```

I want to store this result to the temporary table for further reporting.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try the below query. You will have to use `INTO`.

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

set @cols=STUFF((select distinct ',[' + LTRIM(rtrim(year(Dt)))+']' 
from temp 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

EXEC('select * INTO ##temptable from 
    (select YEAR(Dt)[year],Software,Ver from temp)T
    Pivot(count([year]) for [year] in ('+@cols+'))PVT')
```